# Jquery Image AND link swap using same variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, replace

I have a product page that has multiple images, with a large image shown in the main box, and some thumbnails of additional images underneath. WHen clicking on the main image, Fancybox fires and you get to see an even larger image in a lightbox effect.

I'm using jquery to swap out images on the page, and this works fine:

```
<script>
$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
$('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('width=80&height=80','width=470&height=525'));
});
</script>
```

And code in the main area:

```
<div class="prodrightcolumn">
    <div class="productmainimage" id="panel">
        <a id="largeLink" href="~/images/@product.Image1"  rel="gallery2" class="fancybox" title="@product.Title">
            <img id="largeImage" src="~/images/@product.Image1?width=470&height=525&mode=crop" alt="@product.Title" />
        </a>
    </div>

        <div id="thumbs">
            @if (product.image1 != ""){<div class="productsmallimage"><img src="~/images/@product.Image1?width=80&height=80&mode=crop" alt="@product.Title" /></div>}        
            @if (product.image2 != ""){<div class="productsmallimage"><img src="~/images/@product.Image2?width=80&height=80&mode=crop" alt="@product.Title" /></div>}
            @if (product.image3 != ""){<div class="productsmallimage"><img src="~/images/@product.Image3?width=80&height=80&mode=crop" alt="@product.Title" /></div>}
            @if (product.image4 != ""){<div class="productsmallimage"><img src="~/images/@product.Image4?width=80&height=80&mode=crop" alt="@product.Title" /></div>}
            @if (product.image5 != ""){<div class="productsmallimageend"><img src="~/images/@product.Image5?width=80&height=80&mode=crop" alt="@product.Title" /></div>}
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I need to do is change the link in the lageLink ID so that FancyBox will open the correct image, and not the default first image. I've tried:

```
$('#largeLink').attr('href',$(this).attr('href'));
```

But it's not working. I'm not that familiar with jquery, so I'm really just feeling my way around. I've tried reading up on some blogs but I'm just not getting it, so I either need more coffee or a much appreciated helping hand if possible.